# Integrating comments from Facebook posts back into Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, facebook

I run a Wordpress site, and we also post all our articles to Facebook. I was wondering if there's a way to automatically fetch comments made on Facebook shares of articles posted on the site back into the comment section of the article on Wordpress. Essentially, I want to consolidate all comments into one format on the site. Furthermore, if someone makes a comment on the article on Wordpress, I would like it so that it would also post onto the "official" share of the post on Facebook on the page attached to the site. I don't particularly care for keeping the built-in comments on Wordpress.

Currently I use Disqus and that has a Facebook login, but it doesn't consolidate comments from Facebook shares of the article onto the blog. Is this doable at all?

Comment: Comment Mirroring, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the instruction 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments
You can import facebook post comments to blog